# Sending mail with attachement using SwiftMailer under PHP Symfony 3.4

Tags: php, email-attachments, swiftmailer, symfony-3.4

How to send attachments with SwitfMailer and Symfony 3.4. When I try to send the mail simply, everything works fine. But **if I add the attached file, the mail is not sent**. Can someone help me?

Here is my code:

```
$mailer = $this->get('mailer');
$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
->setSubject(''.$entity->getIntitule() )
->setFrom(array('dabonnehoda@gmail.com' => 'UNB-LIVE-REZO'))
->setTo('dabonnehoda@gmail.com')
->setCharset('utf-8')
->setContentType('text/html')
->setBody($this->renderView('email/annonceEmail.html.twig', array('message' => $entity->getInformation())));
$message->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath('C:/wamp64/www/unb/web/uploads/diplomes/fichier/file.pdf');
$mailer->send($message);
```

Comment: What happens instead? What have you tried to debug the problem? Does Symfony's profiler help you to spot a problem?

Comment: try checking if the file is readable, https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-readable.php prior to attaching it. Also check the $result = $mailer->send($message); and see. if it is true, then maybe the email is being blocked after you sent it, by your email gateway